# Initialize a class instance in Python by passing an object of the same type

Tags: python

In Python's pathlib module you can create a Path object from another Path and they will be equivalent:

```
p = Path('some/path')
p2 = Path(p)
p == p2
# True
```

I have a File class that I would like to implement this same behavior, where if I pass a File object to the File constructor, it will simply return the original object that was passed in. What is the correct way to do so? Do I need to override the `__new__` method to achieve this?

Comment: "if I pass a File object to the File constructor, it will simply return the original object that was passed in." that's actually *not* what is happening above, you'll note, `p is p2` will evaluate to `False`. they are *equal* but *not identical*. Although, one example of where you will see this behavior is with strings, i.e. `str(some_str) is some_str` *happens* to be true in CPython.

Comment: You could extract the data and create a new instance if it's simple. Or you could check the type and make a deep copy.

Comment: @d.b thanks! That's very helpful. I followed this solution.

Answer (score 1):

As @d.b mentions in the comments, you can "extract the data and create a new instance." This happens to be exactly how `Path` does it, using `@classmethod`s. Here is the key function from the [source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/pathlib.py) (simplified here for clarity), which is called from `__new__`:

```
@classmethod
def _parse_args(cls, args):
    parts = []
    for a in args:
        if isinstance(a, PurePath): # <--- Here
            parts += a._parts       # <---
        else:
            a = os.fspath(a)
            if isinstance(a, str):
                parts.append(str(a))
            else:
                raise TypeError()
    return cls._flavour.parse_parts(parts)
```

Then `p == p2` returns `True` because of the class's definition of `__eq__`, though `p2` is not the original object.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! I ended up implementing a solution extracting the data and creating a new instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the constructor to return the original object then you have to override `__new__` method:

```
def __new__(cls, *args):
    if isinstance(args[0], File):
        return args[0]
    instance = super().__new__(cls, *args)
    # do initialization
    return instance
```

Note that you cannot use `__init__` because it would be called even if no new instance is created.

A cleaner solution is to use a function which return either the instance or a new instance:

```
def File(*args):
    if isinstance (args[0], File_):
        return args[0]
    return File_(*args)
```

where `File_` is the original class